# io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException:Caused by: ZonedDateTime; - How can I use ZonedDateTime on 18 API version?

Tags: java, android

So I'm an amateur Android developer and have an issue.
Our app uses ZonedDateTime but the users who are running Android version below oero are facing crashes and it is probably due to ZonedDateTime, at least that's what the logs say so can someone help me with it, please?

Here's the error:

```
io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: The exception could not be delivered to the consumer because it has already canceled/disposed the flow or the exception has nowhere to go to begin with. Further reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#error-handling | java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/time/ZonedDateTime;
at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:367)
at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:126)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6816)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1563)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1451)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/time/ZonedDateTime;
at com.myapp.myapp.cryptoanalysis.fragment.adapter.RVCardAdapter$1.onNext(RVCardAdapter.java:169)
at com.myapp.myapp.cryptoanalysis.fragment.adapter.RVCardAdapter$1.onNext(RVCardAdapter.java:154)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.drainNormal(ObservableObserveOn.java:201)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.run(ObservableObserveOn.java:255)
at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:124)
... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.time.ZonedDateTime" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myapp.myapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myapp.myapp-1/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
... 12 more
```

Here's the java code which needs to support lower API version:

```
  @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(HistoData histoData) {

                        TimeSeries series = new BaseTimeSeries("Strategy");

                        //TODO make usable on API 21+
                        ZonedDateTime endTime = ZonedDateTime.now().minusDays(historyDays);

                        //loop for each day of results in histodata
                        for (int i = 0; i < histoData.getData().size(); i++) {

                            //create a new base bar
                            Bar bar = new BaseBar(
                                    endTime.plusDays(i),
                                    histoData.getData().get(i).getOpen(),
                                    histoData.getData().get(i).getHigh(),
                                    histoData.getData().get(i).getLow(),
                                    histoData.getData().get(i).getClose(),
                                    histoData.getData().get(i).getVolumeTo()
                            );

                            series.addBar(bar);

                        }


                        //RUN ANALYSIS
                        Signal signal = TechnicalAnalysis.getSignal(series);

                        //INFLATE LAYOUT STUFF
                        cryptoViewHolder.mSignal.setText(signal.getSignalResult());
                        cryptoViewHolder.mRsiValue.setText(String.valueOf((int) signal.getRsiStrength()));
                        cryptoViewHolder.mMomentumValue.setText(String.valueOf((int) signal.getMomentumStrength()));
                        cryptoViewHolder.mEmaValue.setText(String.valueOf((int) signal.getEmaStrength()));
                        //cryptoViewHolder.mSignalStrength.setText("(" + String.valueOf(signal.getSignalStrength()) + ")");


                    }
```

Searching online, I found people suggesting to use this library (https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) but the README isn't noob friendly so I don't know how to use it or re-write the public void onNext(HistoData histoData) method using this lib.

Can someone help, please?

Edit: This code was written by our companies ex-programmer and my PM wants me to fix it.

Comment: Hi, Do you setting the `@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)` on `onNext` only?

Comment: Yes, removing that annotation is causing errors!

Comment: Well, that's mean your `onNext` not running on device lower than **O** version which cause the real problem, you should minimize the annotation scope inside the `onNext` specifically on the `ZonedDateTime` part.

Comment: Removing that annotation throws this error: Call requires API level 26 (current min is 18): java.time.ZonedDateTime#now more..

Comment: This kind of warning don't make the app not able to compile or run, the warning thrown to show you smth wrong. Also you need to minimize the scope of annotation.

Comment: ZonedDateTime ONLY works on API 26+, and my project's minimum API is 18, thus the error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `onNext` itself, **you need to minimize the scope of annotation**, i.e:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            ZonedDateTime endTime = ZonedDateTime.now().minusDays(historyDays);
        } else {
            TODO("VERSION.SDK_INT < O")
        }
```

You will need another *API* for device lower than **O**.

Comment: ZonedDateTime ONLY works on API 26+, and my project's minimum API is 18, thus the error.

Comment: @MegganSam My answer solve the question problem, and you can't use ZoneDateTime within apis lower than 26.

Comment: The issue itself is about ZoneDateTime, please read properly first.